# Does the Golang's regexp package parse regex differently than others?

Tags: regex, go, parsing

Golang isn't behaving as expected when parsing regex. I've tested my reg phrase on regextester and it seems to be working as expected. Here's my code:

```
func main() {
    tags := regexp.MustCompile(`[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]`).Split("foo, bar, baz", -1)
    fmt.Println(tags)
}
```

Golang, in both my local environemnt and the playground, returns [ ,  ,  ] where it should return ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

Comment: All regexp engines parse regexp differently in that they are unique implementations. The problem here is you're using `Split`, which expects a regexp to match *the separator*, but you're passing in a regexp for the full match. For `Split`, the correct regexp would be something like `,\s*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *extract* the matches with [`FindAllString`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString):

```golang
tags := regexp.MustCompile(`[^,\s][^,]*[^,\s]`).FindAllString("foo, bar, baz", -1)
```

See the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3-GycMLCJAI).

Note you do not need to escape a comma anywhere in the regex, `[^\,]` is more succintly written as `[^,]`.